# How to change control value in MasterPage from user control ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to change control value exists in Master page from user control and the scenario is like this:
On user control load method I use a query string parameter called "catID" to get category entity, then I want to set the category title as value of title tag (Category title) ,which locate in Master page .
I tried to change the title in user control page load control but the Master page load method executes earlier.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is an absolutely horrible practice. Totally violates "Separation of concerns" principle and many more. The user control should not be changing the master page, the page should. Further, user control should be agnostic of where it is placed. The way you have it is nothing but tight coupling.

Comment: @Mrchief: +1 but UserControls' purposes are not always separation and reusability but sometimes encapsulation and simplification. In this case the UserControl itself adopts the role of the page as controller and the page only controls the visibility of the containing UserControls. Consider f.e. the scenario of [lazy-loading TabPanels of a TabContainer](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html) where all Panels contain a UserControl with the full functionality of a Page.

Comment: @Tim: that's right the user control here adopts the role of the page..there is only one aspx in my project it controls the visibility of the user control depending on query parameters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Provide a public method in your MasterPage that sets the title, for example:

```
public void setTitle(string title)
{
    this.LblTitle.Text = title;
}
```

Then you can call it from your UserControl(`YourMasterPage` is the actual type of the MasterPage):

```
((YourMasterPage)this.Page.Master).setTitle("new Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a query string parameter you should be able to read "catId" i.e from Masterpage code behind as well and set the title.

EDIT:

Try a property then:
In usercontrol

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyTitle = "SomeTitle";
}
public string MyTitle { get; set; }
```

On masterpage:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl.PreRender += new EventHandler(WebUserControl_PreRender);
}

void WebUserControl_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = WebUserControl.MyTitle;
    this.Header.Title = str;
}
```

Comment: your right I can do this but if I get the category entity in master page and I'm already getting it in the user control it'll be not good.

Comment: this is good but it will not work because I load the user control in default.aspx which has no title tag... just the container and some other tags... the title tag is in Master page

Answer (score 0):

```
 ((Label)Master.FindControl("loadlbl")).Text = "your text";
```